# How do I count hits of each element in a list in Django?

Tags: python, django

So I have a page where multiple articles are listed. (To be precise, TITLES that are outlinked to the articles written on Notion template.) And I want to have a filed in my model that counts the number of clicks of each article. (I don't want to use `django-hitcount` library). 
Let me first show you my code. 
 models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")
    url = models.URLField(max_length=100, default="")
    hits = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

template

```
...
<div class="col text-center">
    {% for q in allArticles %}
        <a href="{{q.url}}"><h2 id={{q.number}}>{{q.title}}</h2></a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
...
```

I was thinking of using `onclick()` event in JavaScript, but then passing data from JavaScript to Django seemed too challenging to me at the moment. 
I'd very much appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: one way is to parse your logs and check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, when you dont take up new challenges you stop learning !

The onclick method looks like the best imo, lets see what others suggest.

honestly, using JS and AJAX to communicate with your django server might be dauting at first but it is quite easy really.

if you know how to create a function in your `views.py` and know a bit of JS, it's just like any other classic functionnality.

Set up your `urls.py` for the view function that will add a click to the counter:

```
path('ajax/add_click', views.add_click name="add_click"),
```

Then, create your view function (pseudo code):

```
def add_click(request):
    # retrieve the article
    article_id = request.GET.get("articleId", None)
    # then retrieve the object in database, add 1 to the counter save and return a response
```

Now the "complicated" part, the ajax request:

```
function add_one_click(articleId) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/ajax/add_click', // you also can use {% url "app_name:add_click" %}
            data: {
                'articleId': articleId,
            },
            success: function() {
                console.log("hit added to article");
            }
        });
    }
```

You need to add JS and Ajax lib to your html template for it to works.

Also you need to pass in the onclick attribute the name of the function + the id of the article
`onclick="add_one_click({{article.id}})"`

One more thing, this type of view, if not protected can lead to get false results.

Comment: Hey thank you very much. However I got this error in my console : ```GET [myUrl]/ajax/add_click?articleId=10 404```. All I know is that 404 is a path error, but I can't figure out what exactly is the problem. Any idea?

Comment: I'm using ```jquery.min.js```. Could this the problem?

Comment: what did you use in the javascript for the url ? 
For the `{% url %]` tag to work, the script needs to be in the .html file, not in an external .js file.

Comment: I modified my answer, I did not include the app name in the url tag. That might be it.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Create a new url that would handle your article click, lets say-

```
path('article/clicked/<article_number>', views.click_handler, name='click_counter')
```

Now, in your template use this url for all the article

```
<div class="col text-center">
    {% for q in allArticles %}
        <a href="{% url 'app_name:click_counter' q.number %}"><h2 id={{q.number}}>{{q.title}}</h2></a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

and in your `views.py` create a new controller

```
def click_handler(request, article_number):
    article = Article.objects.get(number=article_number)
    article.hits += 1
    article.save()
    # now redirect user to the outer link
    return redirect(article.url)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is that each article is out-linked. That's the point where I'm struggling.

Comment: @RyanOh, sry I misunderstood the problem at first, I have updated the answer. See if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having q.url have a new URL(`/article_count?id=q.id`) which you will define on your Django project

```
def article_count(req):
    _id = req.GET.get('id', '')
    # Query Aritcle and get object
    q = Article.objects.get(id=_id)
    # update the fields for clicks
    q.hits += 1
    q.save()
    # redirect the page
    return redirect(q.url)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I can't fully understand the code. As I've mentioned in the post, each article is out-linked to a Notion page. Is your solution still applicable in this case, too?